# How to create tables and User-Defined Records in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following table in Oracle

```
create table x(
  x_id           number,
  x_description  VARCHAR2(40),
  x_date         DATE
)
```

For example, a PL/SQL table of x names is modeled as a database table with three columns, which store a number and character data and date respectively. Although you cannot use SQL statements to manipulate a PL/SQL table, its primary key gives you array-like access to rows.

```
declare
  type tab_x is table of x%rowtype;
  row  x%rowtype;
  list tab_x;
begin
  begin
    list.delete;
  exception
    when collection_is_null then
      list := tab_x();
  end;

  row.observacion := 'Jorge';
  row.numero      := '1';
  row.fch_ins     := sysdate;
  list.extend;
  list(list.last) := row;

  row.observacion := 'Andrea';
  row.numero      := '2';
  row.fch_ins     := sysdate;
  list.extend;
  list(list.last) := row;

  row.observacion := 'Jose';
  row.numero      := '3';
  row.fch_ins     := sysdate;
  list.extend;
  list(list.last) := row;

  row.observacion := 'Lucas';
  row.numero      := '4';
  row.fch_ins     := sysdate;
  list.extend;
  list(list.last) := row;

  for i in list.first .. list.last loop
    row := list(i); 
    dbms_output.put_line(row.x_id ||' - '|| row.x_description ||' - '|| row.x_date);
  end loop;

end;
```

Output:

1 - Jorge - 13/12/16

2 - Jose - 13/12/16

3 - Andrea - 13/12/16

4 - Lucas - 13/12/16

**How can I do this in PostgreSQL?**

Comment: Or, you could use the `RETURNS SETOF x` (or the even more explicit/custom `RETURNS TABLE`) & you can avoid temp tables with [`RETURN NEXT` / `RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN65553)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK "table of" does not exist in pg but you can use temporary tables for it. You work with them with usual INSERT/ UPDATE/ DELETE commands. Also %rowtype works on them as usual. Temp table lives only untill session exists.

Plus - you probably know "dbms_output.put_line" is "raise NOTICE" in pg.

Plus to run it as anonymous block use "DO $$ ...here your code ... $$"